# How to fix youtube live chat in HTML

Tags: html, youtube

I'm new to code and I want to implement a code that puts the youtube live chat onto the page. Right now it is refusing to connect.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="pewdiepie" height="80px" width="300px" frameborder="0" src= "https://akshatmittal.com/youtube-realtime/embed/#!/UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA" style="border: 0; width:300px; height:80px; background-color: transparent;"></iframe>
        <p>
        <iframe id="tseries" height="80px" width="300px" frameborder="0" src="https://akshatmittal.com/youtube-realtime/embed/#!/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw" style="border: 0; width:300px; height:80px; background-color: transparent;"></iframe>
        <p>
        <iframe height="500" width="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=UVxU2HzPGug&embed_domain=<MY_IP>" style="border: 0; width:300px; height:100px; background-color: transparent;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? And how I can fix it? By the way I hid my IP address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52468303 (with more answers available there).

Answer (score 1):

To embed a youtube live chat, the link must be like this:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=<id_video>&embed_domain=<your_domain>"
```

So, to embed your chat on stackoverflow, it will be:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=UVxU2HzPGug&embed_domain=www.stackoverflow.com"
```

**EDIT :**

Here is the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en) from google.

> During a live stream, you can embed live chat on your own side by using an iframe.
>
> Get the video ID for the live stream. You can get the video ID from the watch page URL (youtube.com/watch?v=12345). In this case, the video ID is ‘12345’.
>
> If you chose "Stream now," right-click on the player and select Copy video URL to get the video URL.
>
> Get the domain URL for the site you want to embed chat on. If you're embedding chat on www.example.com/youtube_chat, your embedding domain is "www.example.com."
>
> Combine the embedded URL in the following way: https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=12345&embed_domain=www.example.com.
>
> This is the URL for your iframe. Note the embed_domain must match the the URL of the page you’re embedding the chat on. If they are different, the embedded chat will not load.

Comment: Youtube nowadays sends HTTP header `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` which prevents this feature from working. It's still unknown if this is a bug in youtube or intentional change due security issues.